# Missing layer/object when exporting

Tags: export, physics, layers, rigidbody

i've only been using blender for a few days. However i've been stuck trying to export a project however one of the object in there doesn't export. the only Difference with the object is that it has a 'Rigid body' physics property on it. So it starts out of frame and falls into the frame. This object is showing when I 'Render Image', however when I render using Concierge through the website it doesn't include that render.

[image]

None of the layers seem to be excluded from the renders in the collection panel.

Here is a random frame from the export process
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can bake rigid body physics to keyframes (Object → Rigid body → Bake to Keyframes) and then have a renderfarm-save version of the file.

Comment: I believe this has worked! Really appreciate the help :)